# Is it possible to create read-only observable list?

Tags: javafx, observablelist

I have observable list `ObservableList<Integer> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList()`.

In getter method for `list` I want to return read-only observable list, something like:

```
public ObservableList<Integer> getReadOnlyList() {
     return readOnlyObservableList(list);
}
```

and then listen to read-only list

```
getReadOnlyList().addListener(listChangeListener);
```

So basically I want to return ObservableList list that is synchronized with original list, so that user can register `ListChangeListener` and observe change events, but at the same time prevent user from changing the original list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ObservableList<Integer> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<Integer> roList = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(list);

public ObservableList<Integer> getReadOnlyList() {
  return roList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#unmodifiableObservableList-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) method:

```
public ObservableList<Integer> getReadOnlyList() {
    return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(list);
}
```

see also [JavaFX ReadOnlyListProperty not read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595631/javafx-readonlylistproperty-not-read-only)

Comment: Although this code is generally ok it will result in subtle problems because you won't get informed about changes to the original list because listeners on lists are weak and the garbage collector will collect them